# SSRS. How to change dynamic fields datatype to DateTime for specific values?

Tags: datetime, reporting-services, time, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have report with following design:

[image: design]

And It returns data in following:

[image: data]

As you see in image above there are on every column date + time (format *Datetime*), I need to change type to *Time* and format It to `hh:mm:ss`

How can I do It?

**I've tried**:

`Right Click` on `Tikrinimas1` > `Text Box Properties` > `Number` > `Time` choosen format and clicked `Ok`, but nothing happens, returning the same date+time.

Shall I use expression? If I use following:

```
=IIF(Fields!Tikrinimas1.Value = "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss", CDate(Fields!Tikrinimas1.Value), "hh:mm:ss")
```

I got following in first row: `hh:mm:ss` instead of `15:40:11` and in other rows `#error`

Also I've tried this:

```
=IIF(Fields!Tikrinimas1.Value = "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss", FormatDateTime(Fields!Tikrinimas1.Value), DateFormat.ShortTime)
```

But I got the same problem - in first row `ShortTime`  instead of `15:40:11` and in other rows `#error`

Answer (score 0):

As far as my understanding you want to get rid of Am/Pm. 
for that you can use Format function for example see the expression below

```
=Format(Fields!Tikrinimas1.Value, "MM/dd/yy h:mm:ss")
```

[check this link for different date/time formats](http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2013/07/12/formatting-dates-ssrs/)

[formatting datetimes](http://dattatreysindol.com/2011/02/10/formatting-date-and-time-in-sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs-reports/)

hope this might help